# Save checkbox value in database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form like this

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <% counter = 1 %>
    <% @semester.each do |semester|  %>
        <% checkboxs = "subchecked" + counter.to_s %>
        <%= check_box_tag(checkboxs, semester.id) %>
        <%= label_tag(checkboxs, semester.name) %>
        <% counter = counter + 1 %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

and In my create action I tried something like this

```
def create
    @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])

         sem =  params[:checkboxs]
    name = params[:name]       
    counter = 0

    respond_to do |format|
      if @subject.save

        sem.each do |sem|              
          sem.update_attributes!(:name => name, :semester_id => sem[counter])
          counter = counter + 1
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @subject, notice: 'Subject was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @subject, status: :created, location: @subject }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @subject.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But this doesn't have the values instead it shows error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

My new action
      def new
        @subject = Subject.new
        @semester = Semester.all
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @subject }
        end
      end
```

Comment: post code for 'new' action.. problem is not in create action.. but the action which renders your page

Answer (score 0):

You should check the data that comes in your post. Your post values don't seem to be named "checkboxs" but "subchecked1"..."subcheckedN". That's probably what's failing.

Change

```
<% checkboxs = "subchecked" + counter.to_s %>
```

to

```
<% checkboxs = "subchecked[#{counter.to_s}]" %>
```

And

```
sem =  params[:checkboxs]
```

to

```
sem =  params[:subchecked]
```

Comment: you are right, post values are like  "subchecked1"..."subcheckedN" but now I get this error ' NoMethodError in SubjectsController#create

undefined method `update_attributes!' for ["1", "3"]:Array'

Comment: Yes, you are receiving ids in that case, if you want to update objects, you're going to have to do something like ```Semester.find(sem)```. If you want more detail on how to do that you should post your model in the question (or a new one).

Comment: How can I receive the values of the checkbox then?